# How to set fabric.io Beta Distribution e-mails to be sent out through Jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, twitter-fabric

Does anyone know how to get Fabric.io Beta Distribution e-mails to be sent out through Jenkins? I have a Jenkins job that builds and uploads correctly, but the users are never added to the distribution and no e-mails are sent out. Thank you!

The gradle tasks I have configured in Jenkins are:

```
assembleProdDebug

crashlyticsUploadDistributionProdDebug -DbetaDistributionEmails="darranx1a23@hotmail.com, darran1a23@gmail.com, darran1a23@whereisdarran.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was add "ext.betaDistributionEmails=betaTesters" to the build.gradle for the app module as can be seen below:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // Run code coverage reports by default on debug builds.
        testCoverageEnabled = true
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="Release Notes for this build."
        ext.betaDistributionEmails=betaTesters


    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

In my gradle.properties file for the project (which I don't check into a public git repo) I have the following:

```
betaTesters="darranx1a23@hotmail.com, darran1a23@gmail.com, darran1a23@whereisdarran.com"
```

Now we can execute the assembleProdDebug task and then the crashlyticsUploadDistributionProdDebug task and the new builds get sent to beta testers!

Apparently you can also pass in CLI arguments like this too:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/10/gradle-goodness-pass-command-line.html

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

It looks like the syntax you have is for an Ant based distribution instead of Gradle.

For Gradle, [referenced from the docs site](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html), you would want to use:

```
ext.betaDistributionEmails="darranx1a23@hotmail.com, darran1a23@gmail.com, darran1a23@whereisdarran.com"
```